# How do I pass a variable from GAS to HTML and back?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am using GAS to create a web app. I have a doGet that generates the HTML page for the web app and a button on the web app that triggers a script. When I create the HTML page, there is a variable that I need to send to the web app that is then sent back to the script. That variable isn't used in the HTML page other than just transferring it.

Here is a minimal example of what I want to do:
My `doGet()` creates the HTML and passes the variable `foo` to the page

```
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
  var foo = "12345";
  htmlOutput.foo = foo;
  return htmlOutput.evaluate().setTitle('Sample');
}
```

The HTML page has a button that, when clicked, should pass the variable `foo` back to GAS to run the function `checkOut`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <button id="btn" onclick="doStuff()">Click Here</button>
  <script>
    function doStuff(){
      google.script.run.checkOut(foo);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, `checkOut` just displays `foo`

```
function checkOut(foo){
  Logger.log(foo);
}
```

I don't want foo displayed anywhere on the HTML page, but what should I add in order to get it sent back to GAS?

TIA

Comment: Generally the client side (html) has to initiate the action however you can use templated html to load data on the html before it is rendered in the client  and  going from html to the server you can use google.script.run

Comment: Look at [google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))

Comment: Have  you considered the used of scriptlets? In any case, please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

## SUGGESTION

As what the [TheWizEd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3656739/thewized) has commented, you can also achieve your goal using the [`withSuccessHandler()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction). You may check this tweaked script below using a different implementation:

> ***Code.gs***

```
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
  return htmlOutput.evaluate().setTitle('Sample');
}

function setupFoo(){ //Define a value for the "foo"
  return "12345";
}

function checkOut(foo){
  Logger.log(foo);
}
```

> ***page.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn" onclick="doStuff()">Click Here</button>
  <script>
    function onSuccess(foo) {
        google.script.run.checkOut(foo); //on Success will pass back the foo value to GAS function "checkOut"
      }

      function doStuff(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).setupFoo(); //Run "setupFoo" function & pass its returned value to the "withSuccessHandler" function named "onSuccess"
      }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Demonstration

- *After clicking the `Click Here` button on the web app, `checkOut` will log the **foo** value*:

> [image]

Comment: @Teed Ferguson If we answered your question, you may want to click the accept/up-vote button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. That way, they'll be easily recommended  to your post on their searches without the need of posting a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use a value of `foo` in the function of `checkOut` at Google Apps Script side.
- From `That variable isn't used in the HTML page other than just transferring it.` and `I don't want foo displayed anywhere on the HTML page`, you want to achieve this without including the value of `foo` in the HTML data.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, the value of `foo` is used with the scriptlets. This has already been mentioned in the comment.

In this method, the value of `foo` is shown in the HTML data like `google.script.run.checkOut("12345")`. I'm worried that this might not your expected situation from `I don't want foo displayed anywhere on the HTML page`. How about this?

##### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
  var foo = "12345";
  htmlOutput.foo = foo;
  return htmlOutput.evaluate().setTitle('Sample');
}

function checkOut(foo){
  Logger.log(foo);
}
```

##### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <button id="btn" onclick="doStuff()">Click Here</button>
  <script>
    function doStuff(){
      google.script.run.checkOut("<?!= foo ?>");
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, the value of `foo` is used as the background side (Google Apps Script side).

In this method, the value of `foo` is not shown in the HTML data.

##### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var foo = "12345";

  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("sampleKey", foo);
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");
  return htmlOutput.setTitle('Sample');
}

function checkOut(){
  var foo = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("sampleKey");
  Logger.log(foo);
}
```

##### HTML & Javascript side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <button id="btn" onclick="doStuff()">Click Here</button>
  <script>
    function doStuff(){
      google.script.run.checkOut();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### References:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)